# Windows 11 keyboard shortcut to show hidden files

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, windows-11, hidden-file

In Windows 11, what is a quick way using only the keyboard to hide or show hidden files in File Explorer?

Windows 10 provided this through keyboard shortcuts for the ribbon, but the ribbon is gone in Windows 11. The new toolbar seems to have little keyboard support, but hopefully there's a workaround. A utility-based solution such as using AutoHotkey would be fine.

Comment: Where exactly was the option on Windows 10?  I see no option on the Windows 10 File Explorer ribbon to unhide hidden system files. I see "Hide selected items" but once the file is hidden, unless the option is to already display hidden files, it will stay hidden and become unselected.  I was able to find the "Hidden Items" checkbox, but that does not appear to have a keyboard shortcut, associated with it.  I am running a supported version Windows 10.  I must understand how it worked to answer your question.

Comment: @Ramhound: `<Alt>`  **+**  `V` reveals (if collapsed) and selects the `View` ribbon with keyboard shortcuts displayed for the selections. `HH` toggles the `Hidden items` checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Windows 10 using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/):

Save the file as:

## Show Hide Hidden Files Refresh Explorer Windows.ahk

```
#SingleInstance Force

#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass ahk_exe explorer.exe

^h::
If (!A_IsAdmin)  ; IF NOT Admin
{
    Run, *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"  ; Run script as admin
    ExitApp  ; Exit the current instance running without admin privileges
}
RegRead, hidden, HKCU, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, Hidden  ; Get If Files Hidden Or Shown
If hidden contains 1  ; IF Files NOT Hidden
{
    RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKCU, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, Hidden, 2  ; Hide Hidden Files
}
Else  ; ELSE Files Hidden
{
    RegWrite, REG_DWORD, HKCU, Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced, Hidden, 1  ; Show Hidden Files
}
WinGet, windows, List, ahk_exe explorer.exe  ; Get List Explorer Windows
Loop, %windows%
{
    id := windows%A_Index%  ; id
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %id%  ; title
    WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %id%  ; class
    WinGet, exe, ProcessName, ahk_id %id%  ; exe
    ControlSend, DirectUIHWND2, {F5}, %title% ahk_class %class% ahk_exe %exe%  ; Refresh All Explorer Windows
}
Return

#IfWinActive
```

1. `#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass ahk_exe explorer.exe` ensures that the script will be run only if Explorer window is active.
2. `^h::` is the Ctrl+H Hotkey which triggers the code. You can set it to whatever you like.

> The script needs to run as admin so that it can write to registry.

3. `A_IsAdmin` is a built in variable that returns 1 if current user has admin rights, otherwise returns 0.
4. It first checks if user is **NOT** admin (`!A_IsAdmin`).
5. If user is not admin, it runs the same script which it gets the full path with the built in variable `"%A_ScriptFullPath%"`. The `*RunAs` parameter runs the script as admin.
6. `ExitApp` exits the current script if it does not have admin rights.
7. The `Run` command runs the script again with admin rights, now the script has admin rights, it skips the `IF` condition and executes code below.
8. `RegRead` reads the registry entry that shows if hidden files are hidden or shown. If the value is `1` then it hides the hidden files, otherwise it shows them.
9. `WinGet, windows` gets the list of all Explorer windows.
10. `Loop` loops through all Explorer windows, gets the title, class and process of each window, and `ControlSend, DirectUIHWND2, {F5}` refreshes all Explorer windows so that the changes are reflected (files are shown or hidden).

Comment: Why the check for admin? HKCU can be written by any user.

Comment: It didn't write the registry values for me if I didn't run it as admin. If it works without the admin rights for you, then feel free to remove the admin check.